# how to make inbound call from customer to twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to figure out a way to make a inbound call from a number to twilio customer care ( from my trial account ) . I knew the way of making call from twilio to customer care which is kind of below

```
const call_opts = {
                    to: options.to_land,
                    from: twilio_config.from,
                    url: voice_url // which says what to give response if customer picks the call
                  };

const twilio = Twilio(twilio_config.sid, twilio_config.token);      

twilio.makeCall(call_opts, cb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making calls using twilio, you need to create endpoints on your node program to which Twilio can [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) to with the following methods:
- onRecord
- onGather
- onPickUp etc..

If your application doesnt have a public IP, you would probably need to run any http tunnel such as ngrok and provide the url as callback URL for twilio to forward calls onto ur server for processing.

Let me know if this helps your question or if you would need a sample example code snippet for demo. We have been using Twilio's functionalities extensively and I would be glad to help where I can.